# Color the sides of a 3D box

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have wrote this latex code to draw a 3D box.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}



\draw (0,0)
to[short](0,3) node[above] {D}
to[short](3,3) node[above] {C}
to[short](3,0) node[above] {G}
to[short](0,0) node[above] {H}
(1,2)
to[short](4,2) node[above] {B}
to[short](4,-1) node[above] {F}
to[short](1,-1) node[above] {E}
to[short](1,2) node[above] {A}
(0,3) to[short] (1,2)
(3,3) to[short] (4,2)
(0,0) to[short] (1,-1)
(3,0) to[short] (4,-1);



\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I want to color the ABCD, ADHE, BCGH sides. How do I color these sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (saving coordinates of corners for later use)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}

\draw (0,0)
to[short](0,3) coordinate[label=above:$D$] (D)
to[short](3,3) coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C)
to[short](3,0) coordinate[label=above:$G$] (G)
to[short](0,0) coordinate[label=above:$H$] (H)
(1,2)
to[short](4,2) coordinate[label=above:$B$] (B)
to[short](4,-1)coordinate[label=above:$F$] (F)
to[short](1,-1)coordinate[label=above:$E$] (E)
to[short](1,2) coordinate[label=above:$A$] (A)
(D) to[short] (A)
(C) to[short] (B)
(H) to[short] (E)
(G) to[short] (F);
\fill[orange,opacity=0.4](A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;

\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]